# Comparing hashses in C

Tags: c

Hi I am comparing the hashes and I can't get the correct output. So please can you guys help me out.

```
for(int i=0;i<len;i++)
{   
    if(hash1[i]==hash2[i])
    {
        return 1;
        break;
    }
    else
        return 0;
    break;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to `break` on match and not on mismatch?

Comment: moreover, what are the types of  `hash1` and `hash2`?

Comment: @SouravGhosh When I deleted break, it didn't work and only matched the first one only.

Comment: @SouravGhosh hash1 and hash2 are the arrays and len is the length of the array.

Comment: You should really try some basic debugging before asking a question like this. For example, add debug print `printf("for loop i=%d/%d\n", i, len);` before the `if` line.

Comment: Your code is missing some vital parts - in particular, a `main()` function that compares actual and expected output.  Without that, it's very difficult to guess what was intended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the `return` keyword to early, once the code hits a `return`, it goes out of the `for`-loop. So what you are doing there is comparing just the first element of both hashes.

The `break` statement also breaks the loop cycle, but in your code it never actually reaches this statement, because there is always a `return` before.

You should probably try something like:

```
for (int i=0; i<len; i++) {
    if (hash1[i] != hash2[i]) {
        return 0;
    }
}
return 1;
```

Comment: thanks mate it worked. Appreciated. :)